# posición fixed en mobile no funciona

Tags: html, css3

tengo este codigo que hace que se fije una imagen al hacer scroll, pero el problema es que en version mobile ya no funciona.

la imagen se ve, pero no se fija al hacer scroll

```
.float {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

que podrá ser?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Está dentro de un media screen?

Comment: no, no esta dentro

Comment: A lo mejor esta respuesta de Stack Overflow en ingles te puede ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser#19254147 Lo que dice es que tienes que añadir `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Comment: esa misma también la encontré, pero no me funciono

Comment: no funciona en ningún explorador movil?, si funciona en la web?

Comment: en la web si funciona, pero en móvil no

Answer (score 0):

¿En que navegador lo has probado?
¿Qué etiqueta es la que tiene esa clase?
Generalmente cuando se debe visualizar en móviles, se colocar los márgenes en 0, quizás el z-index de algún elemento varía cuando cambia el tamaño de la pantalla si usas responsive design.

Puedes probar:

```
.flotante { position: fixed; 
            bottom: 0; 
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;// referencial
            height: 10px; // referencial
            background-color: #0f0; // referencial
            z-index: 1000; 
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;// los navegadores de movil no interpretan de la misma forma que los de escritorio la propiedad fixed}
```

Comment: el elemento se ve, el problema es que no se fija al hacer scroll

Comment: Agrega la linea:
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Comment: no me funciono. estoy usando chrome por cierto

Comment: ¿Qué navegador con que versión y que dispositivo móvil usas para hacer las pruebas?

Comment: chrome Versión 71.0.3578.98 (Build oficial) (64 bits), el dispositivo es un android 8.0